# Angular HTTP POST function calls twice

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm calling this service below and passing an object `LocalDetails`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OtherdataService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  sendDBInfo(LocalDetails){
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let body = JSON.stringify(LocalDetails);
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.post('http://hostname/api/requestuPatch/', body, options).map(result => result.json()).pipe(share());
  }
}
```

In the node.js I'm trying to execute one shell script in that I have arguments so I'm converting the post object to array and passing them shell in exec 
node.js code

```
app.post('/api/requestPatch/', function (req, res) {
    var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    var shellargs = [];
    for(myKey in data){
        shellargs.push(data[myKey]);
    }

    var commacommand = 'bash /abc/bbc.sh ' + shellargs;
    var command = commacommand.split(',').join(' ');
    exec(command, function(error,stdout,stderr){
        if(error !== null){
            console.error();
        }
        else{
            res.end("success");
            console.log(stdout)
        }
    })
});
```

but the exec(command) is calling twice. can you please help

Comment: Is just the exec command being called twice or is the whole API handler being called twice? also how many times is the angular service on the front end called and how is it called ? Do you subscribe to an observable or is it Promise Based?

Comment: Need to see code that calls sendDBInfo. Also no need to map to json

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because you are not unsubscribing from the observable, you need to do this:

```
  destroy$ = new Subject<void>();
    ....
    ....
  return this.http.post('http://hostname/api/requestuPatch/', body, options).map(result => result.json()).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$), share());
  ... 
  ...

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
```